# getting public ip address and location of users who visit my website in C# mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a website and I want to store ip address and location of the users who are visiting my website. I tried many ways but the code below gives me the ip of server where my website is hosted and not client's ip.

//First code I tried.

bool GetLan = false;

```
        string visitorIPAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress))
            visitorIPAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress))
            visitorIPAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress) || visitorIPAddress.Trim() == "::1")
        {
            GetLan = true;
            visitorIPAddress = string.Empty;
        }
        if (GetLan)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitorIPAddress))
            {
                //This is for Local(LAN) Connected ID Address
                string stringHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                //Get Ip Host Entry
                IPHostEntry ipHostEntries = Dns.GetHostEntry(stringHostName);
                //Get Ip Address From The Ip Host Entry Address List
                IPAddress[] arrIpAddress = ipHostEntries.AddressList;
                try
                {
                    visitorIPAddress = arrIpAddress[arrIpAddress.Length - 2].ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    try
                    {
                        visitorIPAddress = arrIpAddress[0].ToString();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            arrIpAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(stringHostName);
                            visitorIPAddress = arrIpAddress[0].ToString();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            visitorIPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        var zaz = "";
        zaz = visitorIPAddress.ToString();
```

//second code  i tried

```
string VisitorsIPAddr = string.Empty;
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
        {
            VisitorsIPAddr = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
        }
        else if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
        {
            VisitorsIPAddr = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
```

Comment: have you tries `var ip = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()`?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Request` or [`HttpContext.Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.request?view=netframework-4.8) will contain the client's IP address - you don't need the above boilerplate code.

Try using the [`HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress?view=netframework-4.8) property in .NET Framework:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    string clientIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

    ...
}
```

---

Do note however that if there have been proxy servers between the client & your server, the IP may not be the client's IP but the *proxy server's IP*.

In these cases, you may find the original client IP in the [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) header but there are no guarantees for the presence of this header nor you being aware of the client's real IP in general.

Comment: i have tried using this and still it always gives the ip address of my server.

Comment: You must have some form of relaying proxy or CDN? Try checking the value of the header in the answer?

Comment: Its null.. and i have deployed this code on qa server..there is no proxy there

Comment: Do i need to change settings on server where i host my website?